# Check custom data field value change to trigger activity status change

Tags: custom-fields, civicase, activities

How would you recommend to check data change (with pre and post values) on a custom field (attached to a case) and then to mark an activity in that case as completed?

I have looked at hooks like hook_civicrm_custom and the _pre/_post hooks, but having difficulty getting this to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made this work by applying a modified version of the patch at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-9649 which adds an additional array of the previous values for all the custom fields to the hook_civicrm_custom hook.

There is also a plan to make the _pre and _post hooks consistent by including custom data fields (see https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15261). This will also solve the issue I had when done.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it can already do exactly what you want, but my advice is to first look at the CiviRules extension.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules

Comment: Catorghans, I just wanted to say thanks for the all answers you've been contributing lately! Much appreciated. Cheers, Joe

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I had looked at CiviRules but found it didn't quite work as I needed. It works with the _post hook as a trigger. However I found another way to make this work. See below in the answers.